# what are issue involved in setting textview Border programmatically in android

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

Here i am trying set border programmatically. but i don't know how i can set it .

```
        TextView [] pairs;
        pairs = new TextView[num_match];
        for (int l = 0; l < num_match; l++) {
        pairs[l] = new TextView(getActivity());
        pairs[l].setTextSize(15);
        pairs[l].setLayoutParams(lp);
        pairs[l].setId(l);
        pairs[l].setTag("" + l);
ShapeDrawable mDrawable = new ShapeDrawable(new OvalShape());
          mDrawable.getPaint().setColor(0xff74AC23);
          mDrawable.setBounds(2, 3, 4 + 3, 4 + 4);


        pairs[l].setBackgroundDrawable(mDrawable);
        pairs[l].setText("  " + l * l * l);
        ll.addView(pairs[l]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This has to match the issue:

```
RelativeLayout.Layoutparams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)pairs.getLayoutParams();
params.setMargins(5, 5, 5, 5);
pairs.setLayoutParams(params);
```

**Edit:**
Border color is set up by extending `ShapeDrawable` and use it as an background for a view. See details in [Programmatic Shapes in Android](http://www.betaful.com/2012/01/programmatic-shapes-in-android/).

Comment: how set color of border if your giving code is correct ?